# Program crashes when opening and processing input files

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a program, and I'm running into a small issue. It's reading data from a text file, and when the numbers are in ascending order, it runs fine, but when I have numbers in a random order, it crashes. I've debugged it and traced it to this if statement, but I can't figure out what the heck I did wrong.

```
    if(tempNode != NULL)
        {
            struct doublyLinkNode* temp = new doublyLinkNode;
            temp->nextNode = tempNode;
            temp->previousNode = tempNode->previousNode;
            temp->nodeValue = noToInsert;
            tempNode->previousNode->nextNode = temp;
            tempNode->previousNode= temp;
            list->count++;
            return true;
        } // end if
```

The list building crashes when a new number to be added precedes the current top of the list. I think the pointer is attempting to write to an invalid pointer.

Comment: To little info to help.

Comment: The list building crashes when a new number to be added precedes the current top of the list. I think the pointer is attempting to write to an invalid pointer.

Comment: I don't see any sorting logic in the fragment. It will handle either sorted or random order. What happens when there's no previous node? `tempNode->previousNode->nextNode` will be undefined because it will evaluate to `tempNode->NULL->nextNode` if you are carefully initializing pointers to NULL. And worse if you are not initializing pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is to be expected. You want to insert nodes before the current one (`tempNode`),
and you´re using `tempNode->previousNode` in the code.
If `tempNode` happens to be the first node, what´s `tempNode->previousNode`? Right, `NULL`
(unless you have a circular list, but then you wouldn´t have this problem). That means
`tempNode->previousNode->nextNode = temp;` will crash.

As solution to this part, just make an `if`:

```
if(tempNode->previousNode != NULL) tempNode->previousNode->nextNode = temp;
```

(assuming that everything is initialized properly).   Depending on how you implemented the list, you may need to change the information what the first node is, too.

Comment: How did I miss this? I added an if statement and boom, everything is fine. Thanks a lot, I wish I could buy you a beer.